# whether two sets of stabilizer generators are related by a Clifford circuit

Tags: quantum-computing

I have two stabilizer models each specified with a given set of generators. Let's call the two generating sets $S_1$ and $S_2$. By stabilizer model, I mean putting the generators on unit cells of a lattice. I would like to check whether stabilizer generator sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ are related via a Clifford circuit. Is this possible to check efficiently? Can one put constraints of spatial locality on the Clifford circuit and answer the same question?